# Jenkins error during run deployment

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, mstest

Hi I was running my unit test in Jenkins when I encountered this error

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
Failed                FailedTest1
Failed                FailedTest2
Failed                FailedTest3

0/3 test(s) Passed, 3 Failed

### Summary

Test Run Failed.
  Failed  3

---

Total   3
Results file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BatchTests\BatchTestsResult
Test Settings: Default Test Settings

Run has the following issue(s):
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BatchTests\mml\bin\release\syncfromgbaseeucbatchtests.dll' was not found.
Build step 'Run unit tests with MSTest' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

what is even worse that I do not unstand is that I did not have the reference of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation specified in my project reference, therefore i do not know why the dll is looking for it.

The unit tests however do run properly from visual studio 2012 instead. Any help is appreciated.